# Set HTML options using HTMLAgilityPack or WebRequest

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, webrequest

I have a table that I have pulled from a website, but by default an option is set to only show the past 7 days of history. On the website, there is an option (via a combobox) to display all entries. How can I connect via a WebRequest and retrieve all of the data?

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr");
```

On the website:

```
<select id="date-switcher" class="contest-reload-filter">

<option value="3"> … </option>
<option selected="selected" value="7"> … </option>
<option value="30"> … </option>
<option value="-1"> … </option>

</select>
```

I have never done anything of this nature before, so I'm pretty lost.

Comment: You should try and find out what the post parameters are when you select a different value than 7 on that website. Then you can pass that post data in your WebRequest. There's this FireFox Add-on called Tamper Data, which enables you to find out what the exact post request is, then you can adapt the parameters to your liking. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tamper got me the information I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As @June Paik said, you should inspect in a development tool on the browser (Firefox-Firebug) o Chrome(DevTools) which parameters the site sent, and the type of the request POST/GET. Next you can use `WebClient.UploadValues/UploadString methods to simulate the form sending` like this:

```
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty, Encoding.ASCII);
            Uri formAddress = new Uri("Your address here!");
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1284.2 Safari/537.13";

            parameters["q"] = "http://www.google.com/";
            //Add as many parameters as you detected the request send.

            var response = webClient.UploadString(formAddress, "POST", parameters.ToString());
```

Maybe, if you explain which website your request is comming, I could help you out.